# Merging Sub-list items in R from jSon list file

Tags: json, r, list, nested-lists

So I have this jSon data-set which contains factors, some of which are divided into 1-2 more sub-levels of factors. This is causing problems when I try to extract the list into data.frame format, so my question is thus:

Is there a way to write a section in my script which recognizes levels and sub-levels of a factor, and renames them so that they each become identifiable but separate factors.

example:

```
library(rjson)
jSonData2 <- fromJSON(file="metadata.json")
df <- lapply(jSonData2, function(play){ data.frame(matrix(unlist(play), ncol=67, byrow=T))})
```

and the json file is in the following type of format:

```
 [{
  "md5sum": "23f66008b892aee401c8b63299db50c5", 
  "data_type": "Clinical Supplement", 
  "file_name": "nationwidechildrens.org_clinical.TCGA-AO-A0J7.xml", 
  "file_size": 100296, 
  "data_format": "BCR XML", 
  "submitter_id": null, 
  "access": "open", 
  "state": "live", 
  "file_id": "e1cbf391-eeba-4780-a344-9bf408f3628e", 
  "data_category": "Clinical", 
  "associated_entities": [
    {
      "entity_id": "9536bec0-dae0-4d63-a1b3-956741835243", 
      "case_id": "9536bec0-dae0-4d63-a1b3-956741835243", 
      "entity_submitter_id": "TCGA-AO-A0J7", 
      "entity_type": "case"
    }
  ], 
  "cases": [
    {
      "diagnoses": [
        {
          "classification_of_tumor": "not reported", 
          "last_known_disease_status": "not reported", 
          "updated_datetime": "2017-03-04T16:44:35.784223-06:00", 
          "primary_diagnosis": "c50.9", 
          "submitter_id": "TCGA-AO-A0J7_diagnosis", 
          "tumor_stage": "stage iib", 
          "age_at_diagnosis": 26281.0, 
          "vital_status": "alive", 
          "morphology": "8523/3", 
          "days_to_death": null, 
          "days_to_last_known_disease_status": null, 
          "created_datetime": null, 
          "state": "live", 
          "days_to_recurrence": null, 
          "diagnosis_id": "27b1503c-ceca-56ce-a4b1-e38f5c28c31c", 
          "tumor_grade": "not reported", 
          "treatments": [
            {
              "updated_datetime": "2017-03-04T16:43:59.646072-06:00", 
              "created_datetime": null, 
              "therapeutic_agents": null, 
              "submitter_id": "TCGA-AO-A0J7_treatment", 
              "treatment_id": "c84e41de-78dc-5713-b67c-8d6b74dd086c", 
              "state": "live", 
              "days_to_treatment": null, 
              "treatment_intent_type": null, 
              "treatment_or_therapy": null
            }
          ], 
          "tissue_or_organ_of_origin": "c50.9", 
          "days_to_birth": -26281.0, 
          "progression_or_recurrence": "not reported", 
          "prior_malignancy": "not reported", 
          "site_of_resection_or_biopsy": "c50.9", 
          "days_to_last_follow_up": 618.0
        }
      ], 
      "disease_type": "Breast Invasive Carcinoma", 
      "updated_datetime": "2017-03-04T16:39:19.244769-06:00", 
      "created_datetime": null, 
      "demographic": {
        "updated_datetime": "2017-03-04T16:37:28.862150-06:00", 
        "created_datetime": null, 
        "gender": "female", 
        "year_of_birth": 1938, 
        "submitter_id": "TCGA-AO-A0J7_demographic", 
        "state": "live", 
        "race": "white", 
        "demographic_id": "7e2f36a1-f8bd-5b08-b76a-1d389499998f", 
        "ethnicity": "not hispanic or latino", 
        "year_of_death": null
      }, 
      "submitter_id": "TCGA-AO-A0J7", 
      "project": {
        "project_id": "TCGA-BRCA"
      }, 
      "state": "live", 
      "case_id": "9536bec0-dae0-4d63-a1b3-956741835243", 
      "primary_site": "Breast", 
      "exposures": [
        {
          "cigarettes_per_day": null, 
          "weight": null, 
          "updated_datetime": "2017-03-04T16:37:25.850486-06:00", 
          "alcohol_history": null, 
          "alcohol_intensity": null, 
          "bmi": null, 
          "years_smoked": null, 
          "submitter_id": "TCGA-AO-A0J7_exposure", 
          "created_datetime": null, 
          "state": "live", 
          "exposure_id": "0520198e-d60b-5491-a77e-75a7f2a62827", 
          "height": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "archive": {
    "archive_id": "21b29624-43f6-4100-8d84-38a04ed1277a", 
    "data_type": "TCGA DCC Archive", 
    "updated_datetime": "2017-03-04T16:43:58.641267-06:00", 
    "created_datetime": "2016-04-01T20:46:54.412047-05:00", 
    "file_name": "nationwidechildrens.org_BRCA.bio.Level_1.56.90.0.tar.gz", 
    "md5sum": "a0d358c22121eebd9b2b8c40a7121673", 
    "data_format": "TARGZ", 
    "submitter_id": "nationwidechildrens.org_BRCA.bio.Level_1.56", 
    "state": "live", 
    "data_category": "Archive", 
    "file_size": 1119400, 
    "file_state": "submitted", 
    "revision": 90
  }
}
]
```

for this case, I would want each one to be renamed to : cases_diagnoses_classification_of_tumor etc...

I could obviously do this one-by-one or section by section, but I am curious as to if there is a way to make R recognize that each occurrence of such a sub-level should be renamed to: firstlevel_secondlevel_thirdlevel...... etc.

thanks for your help! I hope this helps other people too.

Comment: Can you clean up your example and make it syntactically valid and reproducible? You're missing all the closing brackets/braces. Are the `"xxx"` values just ignored? Are you using `jsonlite::fromJSON` to read in your data?

Comment: thanks for your response. this part that I showed here is just from the json list file, but yes I'm using rJson package fromJSON command to read my data. I am having separate issues with that (including fact its skipping null values) but now I am just specifically looking for a way to translate these sub-level'd factors using sapply or lapply functions (of which I am testing 3-4 with varying success)

as for the xxx, as this is patient data I simply removed the information , but the objective is to have the factors as column names and the xxx value for each patient files in each row.

Comment: So, to reiterate, it would be really nice if you could provide a *syntactically valid* example so that I can copy/paste and try to work on the problem. Currently, if I run `fromJSON(txt = '<your json example>')` I get a parsing error. I tried completing the brackets, adding `}]}]` at the end, and I still got a parsing error. Please make your JSON valid.

Comment: thanks again Gregor. I have added in a whole data set of the 1000+ that my json contains.. as you can see a few of the levels (cases, assosciated_entities etc) have multiple levels

furthermore I am trying to understand how I can avoid it skipping the null values.. I think its because it reads them as length 0 and so skips ahead. maybe a simple function such as nullValue= "null" or others that I have seen similar to this